# How to delete white spaces with trim() for getting vlookup() working?

Tags: excel, vba, types, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a problem that the values in my table_array have some random white spaces and thus the vlookup() does not work.
I tried this code:

```
Sub del_leerzeichen()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Arbeitsblatt festlegen
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    
    ' Letzte Zeile in der Spalte ermitteln
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Schleife durch die Zellen in Spalte A
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Wert glätten und in derselben Zelle speichern
        ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(ws.Cells(i, "A").Value)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

But it gives me an error "type not compatible"

[image]

This `ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(ws.Cells(i, "A").Value)` is highlighted if I debugg it.

Comment: You can use `Trim` without adding the `WorksheetFunction` before. I prefer to use 'Range' myself `ws.Range("A" & i).Value = Trim(ws.Range("A" & i).Value)`.  Can you share the data in the cell you are getting this error ? If you have an error in the cell, you get a run-time error 13, like **#DIV/0!**

Comment: Do cells A1:An have formulas? If they have you wouldn't want to replace them. However, this message appears when there is a formula that returns an error. With a Debug.print "A" & i before the value assignment you will locate the wrong cell.